# Developing a custom scrollable tabbar using XIB only - objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have to create a Custom scrollable tab bar controller using XIB only, i have a constraint that I can't use storyboard. Im able to develop a custom tabbar by adding a UIView and under it we have scrollview and then four buttons acting as tabbar button. And then when I try to navigate from one controller to other Im getting the navigation button. But I don't need that. This is the how much I achieved right now. [image]

[image]

But I want something like normal tab bar controller and with no animation when switching from one view controller to other view controller . The custom tab controller should behave like a normal tabbar controller but with two constraints 
1. It should be scrollable
2. The project should not use storyboard.

This is the code I have so far written for the app delegate and for custom tab bar controller.

```
Appdelegate
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "CustomTabBarControllerViewController.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {




    // Init YourViewController
    //CustomTabBarControllerViewController *viewController = [[CustomTabBarControllerViewController alloc] init];
    LoginViewController *viewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];


    // Init YourNavigationController
    UINavigationController *navigationContoller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: viewController];

    // Set rootViewController


   // self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

    self.window.rootViewController = navigationContoller;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}


- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    [self saveContext];
}


#pragma mark - Core Data stack

@synthesize persistentContainer = _persistentContainer;

- (NSPersistentContainer *)persistentContainer {
    // The persistent container for the application. This implementation creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the application to it.
    @synchronized (self) {
        if (_persistentContainer == nil) {
            _persistentContainer = [[NSPersistentContainer alloc] initWithName:@"CustomTabBar"];
            [_persistentContainer loadPersistentStoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSPersistentStoreDescription *storeDescription, NSError *error) {
                if (error != nil) {
                    // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                    // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                    /*
                     Typical reasons for an error here include:
                     * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                     * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                     * The device is out of space.
                     * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                     Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                    */
                    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                    abort();
                }
            }];
        }
    }

    return _persistentContainer;
}

#pragma mark - Core Data Saving support

- (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.persistentContainer.viewContext;
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([context hasChanges] && ![context save:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
        abort();
    }
}

@end
```

And this is my custom tabbar controller

//  CustomTabBarControllerViewController.m
//  CustomTabBar

```
#import "CustomTabBarControllerViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


@interface CustomTabBarControllerViewController ()

@end

@implementation CustomTabBarControllerViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTabBarControllerViewController" owner:self options:nil];
    _customUiView.frame=CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-49, self.view.frame.size.width, 49);
    [self.view addSubview:_customUiView];


//    _firstButtonOutlet.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
//    _firstButtonOutlet.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    _customScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(_firstButtonOutlet.frame.size.width*6, 0);
    [self UnSelectAllTheTabs];
}

-(void)UnSelectAllTheTabs
{
    _firstButtonOutlet.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _secondButtonOutlet.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _thirdButtonOutlet.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _fourthButtonOutlet.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//- (IBAction)didTapBarButton:(UIButton *)sender {
//
//   [self UnSelectAllTheTabs];
//    switch (sender.tag) {
//    case 0:
//        {
//            //_firstButtonOutlet.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
////            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstViewController" owner:self options:nil];
//           // self.selectedIndex=0;
//
//            FirstViewController *fc = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
//            [self.navigationController pushViewController:fc animated:YES];
//
//            _firstButtonOutlet.backgroundColor= [UIColor grayColor];
//            self.selectedIndex=0;
//            break;
//        }
//    case 1:
//        {
//
//
//            SecondViewController *sv = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
//            [self.navigationController pushViewController:sv animated:YES];
//
//             _secondButtonOutlet.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
////            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SecondViewController" owner:self options:nil];
//            self.selectedIndex=1;
//            break;
//        }
//    case 2:
//        {
//
//            ThirdViewController *tv = [[ThirdViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:nil];
//            _thirdButtonOutlet.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
//           // [self.navigationController pushViewController:tv animated:YES]
////            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ThirdViewController" owner:self options:nil];
//            self.selectedIndex=2;
//            break;
//        }
//    case 3:
//        {
//           // FourthViewController *fv = [[FourthViewController All]]
//            _fourthButtonOutlet.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
////           // [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FourthViewController" owner:self options:nil];
//            self.selectedIndex=3;
//            break;
//        }
//
//    default:
//        break;
//    }
//
//}


- (IBAction)firstButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {


    _firstButtonOutlet.backgroundColor= [UIColor grayColor];
    _secondButtonOutlet.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _thirdButtonOutlet.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _fourthButtonOutlet.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];


    FirstViewController *fc = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:fc animated:NO];
//    [self.navigationController showViewController:fc sender:nil];
    //
}


- (IBAction)secondButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {


    _secondButtonOutlet.backgroundColor= [UIColor grayColor];
    _thirdButtonOutlet.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _fourthButtonOutlet.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _firstButtonOutlet.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];

    SecondViewController *sv = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sv animated:NO];
}


- (IBAction)thirdButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

    _secondButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _fourthButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _firstButtonOutlet.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _thirdButtonOutlet.backgroundColor= [UIColor grayColor];

    ThirViewController *tv = [[ThirViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ThirViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tv animated:NO];
}



- (IBAction)fourthButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {


    _firstButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _secondButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _thirdButtonOutlet.backgroundColor= [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _fourthButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    FourthViewController *fv = [[FourthViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:fv animated:NO];

}



/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: You must have written some code for what you have achieved so far. Can share it so that one may point out where and what are you doing wrong.

Comment: Ok this is my custom tabbar code. I am editing my post and sharing the code, the I had so far written .

Comment: Don't use constraint, view and scroll view. Just add collection view in the bottom and handle cell as each button. You can add or remove buttons in collection view just adding/ removing data in Data Source. Other selection will be easier.

Comment: First I added a UIView and then under that I added a scroll veiw with four buttons in it . Ive made the buttons scrollable but can seem to navigate from one view controller to next view controller smoothly like in normal tabbar . And one more thing I want my tabbar to persist

Comment: Its worth to have a look in https://github.com/ratulSharker/RSCustomTabbarController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have almost achieved your goal. You have only one issue with your code.

** Search for correct format, I am working in swift and don't have objective c code.

```
    - (IBAction)fourthButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

    _firstButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _secondButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _thirdButtonOutlet.backgroundColor= [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    _fourthButtonOutlet.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    FourthViewController *fv = [[FourthViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FourthViewController" bundle:nil];
   // [self.navigationController pushViewController:fv animated:NO];

    fv.frame = CGRectMake(x:0,y:0,self.view.frame.origin.width,self.view.frame.origin.height - (Your tabbar height));

    //Check if any other view controller is already added to it. Remove that from view and super.


    [self.view addSubview: fv.view];
    [self addChildViewController:fv];
    }
```